# Unable to build existing project after update to Android Studio 1.3

Tags: android

After upgrading to Android Studio 1.3, I am unable to build my project. I am getting error "Grade DSL method not found" I clean build, restarted Android Studio rolled back from build tool 23.1.0rc to 22.0.1 with no luck.

Would anyone know what else I can do to get my app to run -see screen shot[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only thing I needed was to update to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

in the project build.gradle file.

Then restart Android Studio.